# Command line parameters in netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, command-line-arguments

I want to run my program as if I was running it using a terminal. Because I want to do different things depending on what attributes the user of the program provides while running it. Is there any way to do that in netbeans?

Comment: Project Properties->Run->Arguments in 6.9.1 works in Java. I'll bet it's the same for C++.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using Netbeans 7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this tutorial which explains how to specify command line arguments for a C++ project in Netbeans 7.2](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/quickstart.html).

It works very similarly to Java, in that you right-click the project, select Properties, then the Run page, then set the command line options you want to feed your application when running it in Netbeans.